# NumPyArrayToRaster not working

Tags: arcpy, numpy

I am trying to use NumPyArrayToRaster but it does not work. It even doesn't throw me errors, it just stops forever (my file is very small)
So this is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import arcpy
import math
import linecache

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

myarray = np.array([])
workpath = "D:/testing/"
ascpath = workpath + "testing.asc"

ncols = int(linecache.getline(ascpath, 1).split()[1])
nrows = int(linecache.getline(ascpath, 2).split()[1])
xllcorner = float(linecache.getline(ascpath, 3).split()[1])
yllcorner = float(linecache.getline(ascpath, 4).split()[1])
cellsize = float(linecache.getline(ascpath, 5).split()[1])
nodata = int(linecache.getline(ascpath, 6).split()[1])
print ncols, nrows, xllcorner, yllcorner, cellsize, nodata

f = open(ascpath, "r")
readfile = f.readlines()
for line in readfile[6:]:       #after first 6 lines
    token = line.split()
    myarray = np.append(myarray, token)
newarray = np.reshape(myarray, (ncols, nrows))
print newarray
arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(newarray, arcpy.Point(xllcorner,yllcorner), (cellsize), value_to_nodata= nodata)
raster.save(workpath + "test")
f.close()
```

If anyone can spot the problem, please tell me.

Comment: what do you mean by "it just stops forever"?

Comment: What do your print statements report?  Can you add more to isolate where precisely in your script "it just stops forever"?

Comment: Very complicated way instead of using ASCII to raster. Anyway why(cell size). Also I noted what arc gis calls numpy array is not the one at all. Table to numpy array for example produces something very different. Worth checking

Comment: I also cannot see assignment of raster. What are you trying to save?

Comment: I mean if I put it in IDLE it stops working, It still can print newarray, but it stops at where arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster. If I put the code in ArcMap the ArcMap will quit unexpectedly when it runs to this line.
I changed (cellsize) to cellsize but still not working.
I am trying to save a GRID format raster that can be opened in ArcMap

Comment: cellsize shouldn't be a tuple, the raster has to be assigned to something  ... myraster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster( blah blah)... then save it ... myraster.save()

Comment: I tried 
raster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(newarray, arcpy.Point(xllcorner,yllcorner), 1, value_to_nodata= nodata)
But it still doesnt work

Comment: I am thinking if there is a problem in my format of the array,
when I print my array it looks like this
[['5' '6' '2' '5' '6' '2' '1' '8']
 ['6' '5' '1' '1' '6' '2' '2' '10']
 ['3' '3' '3' '3' '1' '1' '7' '1']
 ['4' '2' '5' '3' '3' '3' '9' '1']
 ['3' '1' '4' '2' '2' '2' '2' '3']
 ['1' '1' '5' '2' '2' '1' '2' '3']
 ['3' '3' '2' '1' '1' '2' '2' '2']
 ['2' '2' '6' '4' '5' '6' '1' '1']
 ['2' '2' '7' '3' '2' '2' '4' '1']
 ['4' '3' '9' '2' '2' '2' '6' '2']]
Is it possible that the ' ' should not be there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the problem. It is the format of the array. It seems that I have append lists into it:

```
    token = line.split()
    myarray = np.append(myarray, token)
```

I tried the following instead and it works:

```
    myarray = np.genfromtxt("testing.asc",skiprows=6)
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could change this line from your script:

```
arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(newarray, arcpy.Point(xllcorner,yllcorner), (cellsize), value_to_nodata= nodata)
```

to this:

```
raster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(newarray, arcpy.Point(xllcorner,yllcorner), (cellsize), value_to_nodata= nodata)
```

I see that you did not define raster to save it.

Comment: thanks.
Tried, but doesn't work as well..

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your specific question, but it would be much simpler to use the [ASCII to Raster (Conversion)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/ascii-to-raster.htm) tool.

```py
workpath = "D:/testing/"
ascpath = workpath + "testing.asc"
outpath = workpath + "test"
arcpy.ASCIIToRaster_conversion(ascpath , outpath, "INTEGER")
```